# running a method asychronously

Tags: android, loops, ping, asynchronous

I want to discover my local network and I need to ping all of clients! that it takes time! so I want to run pinging process in several threads to do this faster; and this is my try:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // For example
    // host = "192.168.1.";

    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {

        String ip = host + i;

        new Pinging().execute(ip);
    }
}


private class Pinging extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String ipAddress = params[0];

        Log.d("test", "Pingng " + ipAddress);

        // Ping method

        return null;
    }

}
```

I expect that 254 thread have been made and do their work asynchronously!
But, unfortunately `for`'s loop commands takes ~254 * 3 seconds long.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` uses thread pools in the background, with the default value of 5. So at most 5 threads will be running in parallel. You will probably have to look at [managing your own thread pool](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html)